# How to catch a tab press in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, masm

I'm working on a project in x86 assembly on Windows (MASM), and I need to somehow catch tab presses, but I'm not sure how to do that in assembly (I'm new to it).

I can get get user input with int 21h, but as far as I can tell that only works if the users types the data, then presses enter.

What I need is a way so that if the user presses the tab key, it will run a proc, and then from that proc I can handle what needs to happen.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you're using int21, it sounds like you're writing a DOS program, not a Windows program.

Comment: What do you set AH to in order to read keystrokes?

Comment: @Gabe - I'm guessing it's just a DOS program that he's running in Windows's VDM environment.

Comment: Steve: yeah, I already changed the tags for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use:

```
mov ah,1 ; get char from keyboard

int 21h

cmp al, 9 ; 9 is ascii of tab

jnz Dont_Call

Call Proc_Name

Dont_Call:

(REST OF CODE)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah01

**DOS INT 21h - DOS Function Codes**

AH = 01h - READ CHARACTER FROM STANDARD INPUT, WITH ECHO

Return: AL = character read

Notes:

^C/^Break are checked 
^P toggles the DOS-internal echo-to-printer flag 
^Z is not interpreted, thus not causing an EOF if input is redirected character is echoed to standard output

See Also: AH=06h, AH=07h, AH=08h, AH=0Ah